# What linters are there for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, lint

Is there a lint-like tool for C#?  I've got the compiler to flag warnings-as-errors, and I've got Stylecop, but these only catch the most egregious errors.  Are there any other must-have tools that point out probably-dumb things I'm doing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Tried [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx)? It's integrated into VS as "Code Analysis"

In the newer versions of Visual Studio, it is called "Microsoft Code Analysis" and can be downloaded from the Visual Studio Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MicrosoftCodeAnalysis2017

Comment: I don't use VS but since you got 4 upvotes in 17 minutes it probably deserves a try.  Installing it now, thanks!

Comment: It works without VS too. But VS is a great tool for .NET development.

Comment: I think it would be pretty hard to convince me that VS (which I have tried, and disliked) is better than Emacs + 15 years of customizations.  It would probably be easier to get me to change keyboard layouts!

Comment: BTW, while you might be comfortable with writing code in Emacs, .NET development is much more than just coding. You can always have VS at hand for visual debugging and other stuff. It doesn't hurt.

Comment: Link for FxCop 10.0  (for .NET 4.0, it's in the 7.1 SDK): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/07/26/fxcop-10-0-is-available.aspx

Answer (score 21):

[SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html) (free, open source) is pretty sweet!

> SonarLint for Visual Studio is based on and benefits from the .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") and its code analysis API to provide a fully-integrated user experience in Visual Studio 2015.
>   SonarLint is free, open source, and available in the Visual Studio Gallery.

Comment: how to run the `lint` in `github actions`?

Comment: That is a separate question - better raise it as such.

Answer (score 20):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) performs a fair bit of static analysis as well as doing a ton of other useful things. Since [version 8.0](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8+EAP) analysis can run in command line mode. Currently I wouldn't code in C# without it.

As well as FxCop, [Gendarme](http://mono-project.com/Gendarme) is another tool to look at (it is Mono's version of FxCop but they are different in approach and the errors that they actually find).

Answer (score 5):

[Gendarme for Mono](http://mono-project.com/Gendarme) is similar to FxCop

Answer (score 0):

You can try .Net Reflector by Red-Gate, you can get it from [here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). Many useful plugins for .Net Reflector are available on CodePlex which you can get it from [here](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins).

Comment: I use Reflector all the time, but AFAICT it's just for inspecting compiled code.  Is there some "show me my stupid mistakes" module I'm missing?

Comment: Good lord yes.  I don't know what you need to do to turn it on (more like, what you've done to turn it off), but dig for it, it's terrific.

Comment: now that Reflector is a commercial product, ILSpy is a good open source alternative ... at least for inspection and disassembly, I've no idea if it has the same sorts of analysis tools

Answer (score -1):

This question already has an answer, but for reference...

You can try [**PVS-Studio**](http://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio/). That's not free, but, IMHO, must have one.
Quote from their site:

> PVS-Studio is a tool used to detect bugs in the source code of programs written in C, C++ and C#.
>
> PVS-Studio performs static code analysis and generates a report that helps a programmer find and fix bugs. PVS-Studio does a wide range of code checks; but it is especially useful to search for misprints and Copy-Paste errors.
>
> The analyzer is designed for developers who use Visual Studio.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: "must have one" - why?