# Limiting method length?

Tags: c#

I've written a unit test to limit a methods line count, but its reporting back incorrect results and failing for everything?

I may not have got some of the math right or detection and was wondering where I went wrong?

I'm looping through all *.cs files, then through each line, marking the start of a method (declaration) and counting how many iterations till it reaches an end statement (`}`),

```
public class LongMethodLineCountTest
{
    private const int MaxLinesForMethod = 60;
    
    [Test]
    public Task Check_All_Methods_Line_Count()
    {
        var path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())?.Parent?.Parent.Parent.FullName;
        
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
            var lastMethodDecLineNumber = 0;
            var lastMethodDecName = string.Empty;
            var lineNumber = 0;
            var methods = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                lineNumber++;

                if (line.Length < 5)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                var isMethodDecLine = line.Contains("private void") ||
                    line.Contains("public Task") ||
                    line.Contains("private Task") ||
                    line.Contains("public async") ||
                    line.Contains("private async");

                var isMethodEndLine = line[4..] == "}";
                
                if (isMethodDecLine)
                {
                    lastMethodDecLineNumber = lineNumber;
                    lastMethodDecName = line;
                }
                else if (isMethodEndLine)
                {
                    methods[lastMethodDecName] = lineNumber - lastMethodDecLineNumber;
                }
            }

            var methodsTooBig = methods.Where(x => x.Value > MaxLinesForMethod).ToList();

            if (methodsTooBig.Count != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", methodsTooBig.Select(x => x.Key)));
            }
            
            Assert.That(methods.Values, Has.All.LessThanOrEqualTo(MaxLinesForMethod));
        }
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is _linting_, rather than unit tests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748631/what-linters-are-there-for-c

Comment: Linters are for making your code pretty, no? This is tests for code quality.

Comment: Parsing c# isn't a simple task. I don't have experience in this but from what I hear I suggest to look into writing an analyser maybe? something roslyn based I'm guessing.

Comment: Aside from this being a *really* bad way to check code quality, don't use a unit test to do this, write a code analyser.

Comment: Also, you miss all sorts of things here, what about `internal async` or `protected` or `private<space><space>void` or any method that doesn't return a void and isnt' async etc. etc.

Comment: Also the `var isMethodDecLine...` bit can be written as a single line, just remove the newlines, that affects your line count without changing complexity.

Comment: also, if this is about code quality, I'd say 'method complexity' is a better metric than line number count: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1502

Answer (score 1):

Trying to parse C# isn't for the faint-hearted. Luckily, there's already a compiler you can use from a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/) :-) So, I had a go at using [Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/) for the first time, and it's fairly easy to accomplish what you want:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
```

Then, you can parse the C# code and analyze methods using `CSharpSyntaxWalker` (I found an example [here](https://joshvarty.com/2014/07/26/learn-roslyn-now-part-4-csharpsyntaxwalker/)):

```cs
var code = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
var root = tree.GetRoot();

var walker = new MethodWalker();
walker.Visit(root);

class MethodWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var lineSpan = node.GetLocation().GetLineSpan();
        var start = lineSpan.StartLinePosition.Line;
        var end = lineSpan.EndLinePosition.Line;
        var count = end - start + 1; // including declaration

        Console.WriteLine($"Method found: {node.Identifier.ValueText}, number of lines: {count}");

        base.VisitMethodDeclaration(node);
    }
}
```

Also [this post](https://medium.com/pvs-studio/creating-roslyn-api-based-static-analyzer-for-c-c0d7c27489f9) gives a few more examples of walking the syntax tree, as well as creating an analyser.

I think the right approach, as already mentioned in the question comments, is by writing your own analyzer. However, you should also be able to use it within unit tests. (Obviously, nobody is suggesting this is a *unit test* but I get it; sometimes you have to be pragmatic and use the tools you have and understand best.)

Answer (score -1):

Had to make some edits but this should work

```
public class LongMethodLineCountTest
{
    private const int MaxLinesForMethod = 100;

    private readonly List<string> _excluded = new()
    {
        "class:method"
    };
    
    [Test]
    public Task Check_All_Methods_Line_Count()
    {
        var path = Directory
            .GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            ?.Parent?.Parent.Parent.FullName;

        var fails = 0;

        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var className = file.Split("/").Last().Replace(".cs", "");
            var content = File.ReadAllText(file);

            if (!content.Contains("public class"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            var lines = content.Split(Environment.NewLine).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
            var lastMethodDecLineNumber = 0;
            var lastMethodDecName = string.Empty;
            var lineNumber = 0;
            var methods = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                lineNumber++;

                if (line.Length < 5)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var isMethodDecLine =
                    line.Contains("void")
                    || line.Contains("public Task")
                    || line.Contains("private Task")
                    || line.Contains("public async")
                    || line.Contains("private async");

                var isMethodEndLine = line[4..] == "}";

                if (isMethodDecLine)
                {
                    var methodName = line.Split(" ").First(x => x.Contains("(")).Split("(")[0];
                    
                    lastMethodDecLineNumber = lineNumber;
                    lastMethodDecName = $"{className}:{methodName}";
                }
                else if (isMethodEndLine && lastMethodDecLineNumber != 0)
                {
                    methods[lastMethodDecName] = lineNumber - lastMethodDecLineNumber;

                    lastMethodDecLineNumber = 0;
                }
            }

            methods = methods
                .Where(x => !_excluded.Contains(x.Key))
                .ToDictionary();

            var methodsTooBig = methods
                .Where(x => x.Value > MaxLinesForMethod).ToList();

            if (methodsTooBig.Count == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", methodsTooBig.Select(x => x.Key + " was " + x.Value + " lines")));
                
            fails++;
        }

        Assert.That(fails, Is.EqualTo(0));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**